# NSURLDomainError 1005 "The Network Connection Was Lost"

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsurlsession, network-connection

I execute the following two calls one after another in a newly upgraded to Swift 2.0 Project.

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
   authRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
   authRequest.HTTPBody = authData
   authRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   authRequest.addValue("close", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
   authRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
   let authTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(authRequest, completionHandler: { (data : NSData?, response : NSURLResponse? , error : NSError?) -> Void in
       print("Response: \(response)")
       print("Error: \(error)")
       let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       print("Body: \(strData)")
       if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
       {
           if 200 ... 299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
           {
               do
               {
               result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as! Dictionary
               credentials.ClientId = (result["client_id"] as String?)!
               credentials.ClientSecret = (result["client_secret"] as String?)!
               credentials.Username = userDetail.Username
               credentials.Password = userDetail.Password
                   completionHandler(result: true)
                                }
               catch {

               }
           }
           else
           {
               self.RemoveInvalidUserCredentials()
               completionHandler(result: false)
           }

       }

       })
       authTask.resume()
```

Followed by:

```
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
   session.configuration.URLCache = nil
   session.configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1
   tokenRequest.HTTPBody = tokenData
   tokenRequest.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   tokenRequest.addValue("close", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
   tokenRequest.addValue("Basic " + (credentials.encodedClientIdAndSecret() as String), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
   let tokenTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(tokenRequest, completionHandler: {(data : NSData?, response : NSURLResponse? , error : NSError?) -> Void in
       print("Response: \(response)")
       print("Error: \(error)")
       let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       print("Body: \(strData)")
       if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
           if 200 ... 299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
           {
               do
               {
               result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as! Dictionary
               credentials.TokenType = (result["token_type"] as! String?)!
               credentials.Token = (result["access_token"] as! String?)!
               completionHandler(result: true)
               }
               catch{}
           }
       }
   })
   tokenTask.resume()
```

The first code block executes correctly and returns the following:

```
Response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14ffe3e60> { URL: <URL>/authorize } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
"Content-Length" = 115;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Tue, 29 Sep 2015 14:17:52 GMT";
Expires = "-1";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
"Set-Cookie" = ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie=E98BMJ5l56psnnJZRy2fyhRTWVYqw4aJsFqPeV1ktkJGi5_frTJ9-8pbp28TcDAn9ISFj_LqwFwOV7WhP1mfTVPktTGTs2Dr5-hvmnISxFVRc1Rg9CcYf3p-Cbn1w6qOEyuXco9PCmCnlsf54KPuSY6Z7FEcUgOyg2nq5oDyamfB_Y4b1dI-7cIZ3LB6ehoI50rIbc2ca7L7f73H1rhbsmuLRarBYsYehSRHRuKs9ec5-XuN0P1W6yqiQ3OOJMayPmmbi6y4uIhBUu0zoRC2v3k9usmRjubxGy2hqf6n0baTOIDokav0wQq_smR9qDA6nNh09YTS1Mzvf0iQPS2YJa7QrnERlNSixDROhkQVLC8hc3GV8jc9_7iGUhJzLgeVzhnjnVeB7Z311QLcXxGonEzzcWAzPu29tm2LkZgdte4J0kQHc-iTiNjSbgBqV2zVH9v_0JHtZCFGdSxSGptXGfsPr5O9M-EyVX2UNXxIsVI-hfv3p8-_igV96phbWsvWyqyYhVMQ8v61vHxfO2CFIQ; path=/; secure; HttpOnly";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
```

However the second has this error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x14ffe3cc0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://test.acumentive.com/tagmanager/api/v1/tokens, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://test.acumentive.com/tagmanager/api/v1/tokens, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}

I don't have access to the server and have tried different sessions and the same shared session to send the request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved the issue by using NSURLConnection instead of NSURLSession. It appears to be happening due to the session caching the previous connections.

Answer (score 1):

That's the whole point of error 1005 - you have no access to the server. When you send a request to the server, one of two things happens: Either you get access to the server and a status code is returned, or your device never manages to talk to the server, so the server cannot give you a status code. Instead you get an error, usually around #1000.

This one is quite rare, it would mean that your device started talking to the server and then lost the connection (more common when you download a multi megabyte file). Imagine someone pulling a network cable out of your Mac, or imagine you walking out of WiFi range with your iPad, in the middle of a request to the server.

I suggest you change your phone to "Airplane" mode and see what happens - every request will get a similar error, and you should test that your app survives this reasonably well. It should also recover to full functionality when you turn "Airplane" mode off.

Comment: The second request returns a very short message back (2 strings). This happens no matter what - I believe it is linked to the known iOS issue of the application saving connections if it thinks it should keep alive for c. 30secs. I need a work around for that but can't seem to find one